# How to import dataset from notepad/spreadsheet into Matlab GUI

Tags: java, javascript, matlab

I'm new to Matlab.I work with matlab(R2009).

I have created GUI using matlab and i want to import dataset into table that is created     GUI.Dataset contains both categorical and numerical values.I have tried in several ways and       i can import dataset as a figure file and in that figure it can't be modified dataset.Also     i tried another way and take dataset into command window.But i need to have dataset appear     in table in my GUI.

After importing dataset i want to add each variables in the dataset into listbox.By  clicking those variables in listbox it can be able to plot graphs,calculate means,etc...

Thanks .

Comment: Your question is pretty vague and open-ended. We need more information to help you with the *specific* problems you're having. What does the data in your file look like? Are there any short sample pieces of code you can add to your question to show us what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can first import the data from the table with

```
[a, b, c] = xlsread('MyTable.xls');

% and then create the table and set the data with
h = uitable; % or create it directly from the GUI design
set(h, 'data', [1 2 3]);

% or set the data from the readed excel
set(h, 'data', a);
```

[edit] you can run uitabledemo from matlab to see some demo for uitable.